# How to get the view by viewId in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp

How do I get the view by viewId in RCP? And then how to redraw the view?
I want to implement the function that when I click a item form a list, then the related view will redraw and call the function 'createPartControl'.I konw the view's id.So how can I get to it?

This is the view's `createPartControl()` method.

```java
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final List list = new List(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    final ObjDumpParser objdump = new  ObjDumpParser();
    List<DisFunction> funclist = objdump.getTextFunList();
    int funcNum = funclist.size();
    System.out.println("123: " + funcNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < funcNum; i++){
        ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IWorkbenchPage` has the methods to control views:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.showView("view id");
```

The part `createPartControl` will be called when the view is created, on subsequent calls to `showView` it is not called.

The `viewPart` will be an instance of your view class so you can add a method to that to update the view, something like:

```java
MyView myView = (MyView)viewPart;

... call MyView method to update the view
```

Update showing on MyView:

```java
public class MyView extends ViewPart
{
  private List list;

  public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
  {
     list = new List.....
  }


  public void update()
  {
    ... update list
  }
}
```

Comment: If I create a function in myView, then how can I get the Composite to add it just like the 'createPartControl(Composite parent)'?

Comment: You should make your controls fields in your class so you can access them from all methods - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the first question.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            IViewPart view = page.findView("BIT_DEC.graphView");
```

The second question bothers me now.

Answer (score 0):

Active workbench window might be null (happened for me while debugging).

```
            IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

            if (workbenchWindow == null) {
                IWorkbenchWindow[] allWindows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
                for (IWorkbenchWindow window : allWindows) {
                    workbenchWindow = window;
                    if (workbenchWindow != null) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (workbenchWindow == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not retrieve workbench window");
            }

            IWorkbenchPage activePage = workbenchWindow.getActivePage();

            try {
                IViewPart viewPart = activePage.showView(id);
                return viewPart;
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                String message = "Could not show view " + id;
                LOG.warn(message, e);
                return null;
            }
```